# How to mock a function that is not part of any class using monkeypatch in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, monkeypatching

Consider a function:

```
def some_function():
    print("some function")
```

and it's mock function:

```
def some_function_dummy():
    print("some function")
```

How do I mock `some_function()` function using `monkeypath.setattr()`?

Something similar to:

`monkeypatch.setattr(<class name>, "some_function", dummy_function)`

Not sure what `<class name>` here should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj` should be the current module:

```py
import sys

# Get the current module
this = sys.modules[__name__]

monkeypatch.setattr(this, "some_function", dummy_function)
```

If `some_function` is inside another file, you need to import this file to your current module:

```py
import another_file

monkeypatch.setattr(another_file, "some_function", dummy_function)
```

Comment: Thanks. And what if `some_function` is in a file other than the test file that contains monkeypatch?

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if this works.